# How to include multiple xml, dll, config files in a python code, but from a different directory at once?

Tags: python, xml, dll

So lets say I have a python code `'C:\Users\apps\server.py'`. The code requires multiple xml, dll, config files to run. One thing I can do is copy all the files in same directory `'C:\Users\apps'` and be done with it.

However, I want the code to retrieve all these files from a child directory `'C:\Users\apps\loadFiles\'`.

I have tried the following code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('path')
```

The above code helps in uploading all the DLLs but not the xmls and configs.

How can we solve this problem using `__init__.py` method ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your path like that
`sys.path.append(r 'C:\Users\apps\loadFiles\')` If that's enough. You can place that in `__init__.py` or in `server.py` as well.
The r before the string will ensure that all the backslashes are not converted.

Comment: I had already tried this method as written in question description.

Comment: I am not sure what files are not being accessed (XMLs, configs or DLLs), but I am getting direct positive results if I copy entire files in 'C:\Users\apps\' directory.

Comment: How do you actually access the files then? Are you loading some cython library? How do you open the xmls?